# Linux Find Binary File

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am attempting to find a binary file in a Linux system using something like this:

```
if [ -f `which $1` ] then
    echo "File Found"
else
    echo "File not Found"
fi
```

while the code works fine the problem is "which" will return a null operator which BASH interprets as something existing so a file always comes back found. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ `which "$1"` != "" ]; then
```

`which` won't return `""` when it finds the binary.

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

After a bit more thought, there is no reason to use `[[ ]]` (or `[ ]` for that matter). There is even no reason to use command substitution either `$()`

```
if which "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

---

If you're using `bash` then please use the `[[ ]]` construct. One of the benefits (among many) is that it doesn't have this problem

```
[[ -f $(which $1) ]] && echo found
```

Also, `` is deprecated, use `$()` instead

Comment: What are you rich? We don't just have square brackets to give away with these economic times.. (which "/bin/ls") .. silent on failure, prints the path on success.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel I think you meant `hash "/bin/ls"`. But you're right, the new answer is sans two parens and four braces. Now everybody can afford to run it!

Answer (score 1):

I like 'hash' for this (if you're a bash user..) (and it's actually more portable behavior than which)

```
hash blahblah
```

bash: hash: lklkj: not found

```
hash /bin/ls <-- silently successful
```

This method works on Linux and OSX similarly, where-as 'which' has different behavior.